# Google map zooming on clicking the pointer

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to zoom the map when I click on the pointer. I am also showing an infobox when I click on the pointer.

```
  function initMap() {
      var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};   
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
               zoom: 4,
               center: uluru   }
               );

     var contentString = 'Info Box';

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                          content: contentString   
                        });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map,
                title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'   
                   });   
       marker.addListener('click', function() {
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);   
                            }); 
             }
```

Now I want to zoom the when I click on the pointer in the meantime it will show the info box.

Your help is appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: Sure, thats possible, what you tried so far?

Comment: I have started trying in the meantime I have asked here. If you please put an answer bellow , it would really be great. Thank you @AdamJeffers

Comment: I am quiet new to google map. Did not use it before.

Comment: Thank you ! I am waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go mate... I've also encapsulated it in its own module.

```
var MapModule = (function(){

    var map = null;
    var marker = null;

    function _initMap() 
    {
        var uluru = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };   
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
           zoom: 4,
           center: uluru   
        });

        var contentString = 'Info Box';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString   
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map,
            title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'   
       });   

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);             
                map.setCenter(this.position);
                map.setZoom(9);
            });
        });
    }

    return{

        initMap: _initMap()
    };

})();

MapModule.initMap;
```

Alternatively, just try this instead...

```
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);             
            map.setCenter(this.position);
            map.setZoom(9);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Great , Thanks. I would like to add something. Can you please help me with zomming out too (When the map is zoomed , after clicking the pointer the zoom will be removed) ?

Comment: Can you describe what you want a little more pls?

Comment: Mate , I have copied and pasted the code into my html file and the map got disappeared !

Comment: Yes , Thank you very much

Comment: Great! You should also look at separating your JS from your HTML at some point. Having it all inline can make it a nightmare later down the line ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);             
  map.setCenter(this.position);
  map.setZoom(5);
 });
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mzu2qte5/3/